# rigid body2D and box collider2D in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using unity, I have a rigid body 2D and box collider2D attached to an object and a simple movement script.  The problem is due to the way the sprite was made I need to offset the box collider in order for it to line up with the sprite but when I offset the box collider and run into a wall (it is a top down game) the object starts to drift and interferes with the movement that is supposed to be happening. If I do not offset the box collider then it does not drift after running into a wall.  I have been stumped on how to fix this all night, any suggestions?

```
private Vector2 movement;
public float moveSpeed = 4;
public Rigidbody2D rb;

 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        movement.Normalize();
        rb.velocity = movement * moveSpeed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just result of collision. When objects with rigidbody colide their velocity gets modified just as you do with your movement script.
You can make your object less bouncy by changing physics material property( create and add it).
Another thing you can do is change drag and mass on rigidbody to make object less floaty.
Lastly i suspect you just have that colider not exactly match your sprite so perhaps use Polygon collider instead?
Lastly you can make it so your velocity is Reduced in every update by small amount so its going to decelerate by default whenever velocity is not being increased.